# how can a kernel process send some data asynchronously to a user level process

Tags: synchronization

I was asked this question in an interview.But the only thing I could think of is allocating a shared memory segment and by some means both kernel and user level processes to write to that segment.Even I am not satisfied with that answer.Can someone please expalin some other mechanism to do so?
Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think they probably wanted to hear about the NetLink Interface. This interface provides an API for a kernel process and user process to communicate through which looks just like a socket, and is considered a successor to ioctl which is easier to use and asynchronous.

Overview here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356

Answer (score 1):

They probably wanted to hear about APC ([Asynchronous Procedure Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: interesting!.The interivew was for a Linux position.Is something similar available in Linux as well?

Answer (score 0):

How about having a proc file as message passing mechanism. It can be accessible from both kernel and user space?

Comment: Also, results may get eventually posted into a pre-allocated memory buffer.

Comment: That is definitely possible.but given that it was an interview contest,I wanted to know if there was something more routine and usual that he was looking for,that I don't know about.?